# Add writing permission to PHP on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I need a PHP script to have writing permission in a directory. PHP 5.3 is running as FastCGI under IIS 7 with windows server 2008 as OP. On my php error logs, I got "permission denied" when the script attempts to write a file.

How can I sort this out? I tried to give all right to IIS_IUSR and to IUSR_myservername (with a right click on my folder) but it didn't work.

Any help would be very appreciate,

Regards,

Julien

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have the same setup and I have to give write permission to:

- `IUSR`
- `IIS AppPool\<<AppPoolName>>`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works when I give writing permission to IUSR!

Comment: You also need to do an `iisreset` for php to reload.

Comment: @svandragt because if your application runs with 'application pool identity' this is the account it uses

Comment: In My case there was no need to do iisreset, only giving write permission to IUSR done the trick.

Comment: <<AppPoolName>> could be DefaultAppPool

Comment: Remember in the Security settings to change the "From this location" to the server's local name and not the domain name otherwise the user won't be found.

Comment: This is answer only true if you're using purely anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 37):

Actually, it's a little bit more complicated.

The first thing to do is to create a simple PHP file on the concerned website. (It's important to create the file on the concerned website because each website can have a different setting.) The content of this file should be:

```
<?php var_dump(ini_get('fastcgi.impersonate')); ?>
```

Navigate to this file using a browser.

** Case 1 **

If your browser shows :

```
string(1) "1"
```

Then, you need to execute the following command (you need to replace "Default Web Site" by the name you gave to your website in IIS) :

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "Default Web Site" ^
/section:anonymousAuthentication
```

You will receive an answer which looks like this :

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
    </authentication>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The information you are looking for is the value of the `username` attribute of the `anonymousAutthentification` tag.

- If this value is not empty, its content is the name of the user you need to give write permissions to.
- If this value is empty or if the attribute is simply missing, you need to give write permissions to `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName` (replace "AppPoolName" with the name of your website's application pool).

** Case 2 **

If your browser shows :

```
string(1) "0"
```

You need to give write permissions to `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName` (replace "AppPoolName" with the name of your website's application pool).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail. I'm always a bit antsy when an answer is just "x" without saying how to find out, or why it's "x"

Comment: Where to execute the command? In cmd or in some specific shell?

Comment: @tristan Charbonnier Sorry to bump an old thread but do you know how to do the app pool permissions for AD and network drives?

Comment: This needs more upvotes! ...after 4 days of search related to "Missing a temporary folder." issue in WordPress, I finally understood that its the IIS AppPool that needs permission on the PHP upload_tmp_dir folder not on WP_TEMP_DIR. thanks mate!

Comment: To get the appPoolName click on the site in IIS and then click on Basic Settings in the right pane

Comment: This is the more complete answer.  If using non-anonymous authentication, your php-cgi.exe is running as an IIS AppPool user but IMPERSONATING someone (Nod to ProcMon).  The impersonated user needs permission to write/modify the log.  For me, I'm using Windows Authentication, so to my error log I added my domain\MyStaff ad group.  domain\Domain Users may work if you need broader SSO permissions, but... least privilege always.

Answer (score 9):

You need to give *PHP* writing permission, not IIS. This means the user account that PHP is running on needs permission (probably the same one IIS is running on).

Comment: How do you tell which account PHP is running on?

Comment: php-cgi.exe will spawn from w3wp.exe and have the same context.  So like tomfumb says above grant the Windows security context 'IIS APPPOOL\MyAppName' write access to the folder in question.

Comment: To know exactly which user you need to give write permissions to, check my answer.