# Change CHMOD of a file in PHP for specific user

Tags: php, asp.net, json, ajax

I have an admin panel which is coded with ASP.net (C#). I have a textarea like wordpress (redactor) and i am trying to upload image with it. I am using PHP file to make upload but after everytime  I upload an image, I encounter with IIS "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." error while displaying it. I would like to add 755 Permission to IIS_IUSR every timem after file upload. Is it possible?

Here is my php code:

```
    $dir = 'assets/images/content/';

    $_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

    if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
    || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
    {



        // setting file's mysterious name
        $filename = md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';
        $file = $dir.$filename;

        // copying
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

        chmod($file, 0777);

        // displaying file
        $array = array(
            'filelink' => 'assets/images/content/'.$filename
        );

        echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));

    }
```

Comment: You are using IIS or apache?

Comment: `stripslashes(json_encode())` is horribly bad. json can/will add **NECESSARY** escaping backslashes to the data being encoded, which stripslashes will then happily remove, corrupting the json.

Comment: Hmm haven't worked with IIS 8 but IIS 7 didn't  use those file modes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887131/add-writing-permission-to-php-on-iis-7

Comment: @chris85 already checked that topic but doesnt work on IIS 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my TEMP folder permissions and its fixed. I hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

try this: Computer Management (right click on my computer and select Manage) --> Local Users and Groups --> Users --> Select IUSR_MACHINENAME (ie,IUSR_TOMATO-CLOWNFIS) --> Right click Properties --> Make sure it is a member of IIS_WPG and users and not Guests.

Comment: There are no users which start with IUSR. ADMINISTRATOR,IME_ADMIN, IME_USER, ENTRENIX, MYadmin, Statsx are the users.