# How to solve the Warning error : Warning: rename(...,...) [function.rename]: No error in

Tags: php

The Unlink works perfectly.

```
if ( file_exists("result/feed/kalo/Cnf.txt" ) && file_exists("result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt")){
        unlink("result/feed/kalo/Cnf.txt");

        if ( ! rename("result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt","result/feed/vor/Cnm1.txt") ) {
            echo 'Não renomeou para Cnm1 !';
        }
    }
```

Yet, I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: rename(result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt,result/feed/vor/Cnm1.txt) [function.rename]: No error in C:\wamp2\www\beed\loof.php on line 57
>   Não renomeou para Cnm1 !

Comment: everything needs to be in English

Comment: This is __English__ speaking site.

Comment: You can use pt.stackoverflow.com or es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check folder/file permissions and paths.

Comment: btw, you unlinked the file yet you're trying to rename something that was deleted. Edit: or one of those doesn't exist and using the wrong operator.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Deleted file is `...Cnf.txt`, not `Cnm.txt` or `Cnm1.txt`. Not sure if the others exist though..

Comment: @chris85 True, yet something got deleted and tried to be renamed. Or their paths/files are off/incorrect or what I said above there. Probably need an `||` and not `&&`.

Comment: I tried giving an unlink but gave permission denied

Comment: there you go; I was right about my comment up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I tried giving an unlink but gave permission denied – Ricardo Schieck 33 secs ago "*

You need to assign proper permissions to folders and files in order to be modified.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php
- [How do I set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)
  (on Linux)
- [Setting File Permissions in Windows with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851821/setting-file-permissions-in-windows-with-php)
  (in Windows)
- [Add writing permission to PHP on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887131/add-writing-permission-to-php-on-iis-7)
  (on IIS 7)

Your path assignments may also be off, and you may need to go from the server's root.

I.e.: (you will need to use the actual path from your server)

```
/var/user/public/result/feed/kalo/Cnf.txt
```

and applying that logic to all your other assignments.

Plus, you may need to change your `&&` operator to an `||` being "OR" rather than `&&` being "AND".

Use error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and make sure that the file (or files) to be renamed exist.

Comment: I try to put all the necessary permissions , but not works ... The error  reporting say to me the same thing , permission denied...

Comment: @RicardoSchieck It's definitely a permissions issue and I've included a few links about this and how to do it, depending on the OS you're using.

Comment: Yes ! I try to do it with the windows link , but doesn't works.. I try the chmod and the chown , but the chown doesn't set ...

Comment: I was do changes my operator and make 'if the file exist' , and the file exist...

Comment: `if ( file_exists("result/feed/kalo/Cnf.txt" ) && file_exists("result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt"))` - both files must exist with the `&&` operator which means "AND". If one of those does not exist, you need to use the `||` operator which means "OR" - `if ( file_exists("result/feed/kalo/Cnf.txt" ) || file_exists("result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt"))` @RicardoSchieck

Comment: @RicardoSchieck also `if ( ! rename("result/feed/vor/Cnm.txt"` that must also exist in order for it to be renamed and using a path example I shown as an example in my answer.