# Failed image upload Laravel and Windows Server 2019

Tags: php, laravel, windows

I am developing a Laravel application, which works fine locally but when deployed to Windows Server 2019, the image upload functionality fails with the below stack trace. I am using the Laravel Spatie Media library for handling the image uploads. The server PHP version is 7.4. I use the latest version of IIS.

```php
    if ($request->exists("product_logo")) {
        $temp_file = $request->file('product_logo');

        if (getimagesize($temp_file)) {
            $allowedMimes = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'];
            $product_logo_mime = $temp_file->getMimeType();

            if (in_array($product_logo_mime, $allowedMimes)) {
                $product->clearMediaCollection();
                $product->addMediaFromRequest('product_logo')->toMediaCollection();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
RuntimeException: The file  cannot be opened. in file C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\nyholm\psr7\src\Factory\Psr17Factory.php on line 44

#0 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\symfony\psr-http-message-bridge\Factory\PsrHttpFactory.php(114): Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory-&gt;createStreamFromFile()
#1 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\symfony\psr-http-message-bridge\Factory\PsrHttpFactory.php(96): Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory-&gt;createUploadedFile()
#2 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\symfony\psr-http-message-bridge\Factory\PsrHttpFactory.php(68): Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory-&gt;getFiles()
#3 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Guards\TokenGuard.php(201): Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory-&gt;createRequest()
#4 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Guards\TokenGuard.php(147): Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard-&gt;getPsrRequestViaBearerToken()
#5 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Guards\TokenGuard.php(110): Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard-&gt;authenticateViaBearerToken()
#6 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PassportServiceProvider.php(297): Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard-&gt;user()
#7 [internal function]: Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider-&gt;Laravel\Passport\{closure}()
#8 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard.php(58): call_user_func()
#9 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers.php(60): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard-&gt;user()
#10 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(63): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard-&gt;check()
#11 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(42): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;authenticate()
#12 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;handle()
#13 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#14 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(693): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#15 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(668): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack()
#16 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(634): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute()
#17 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(623): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute()
#18 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch()
#19 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#20 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#21 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#22 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#23 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#24 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#25 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle()
#26 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(87): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#27 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle()
#28 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#29 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors-&gt;handle()
#30 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#31 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies-&gt;handle()
#32 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#33 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#34 C:\PROJECT_125\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter()
#35 C:\inetpub\PROJECT_125\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle()
#36 {main}
```

This is my setup:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/cashier": "^12.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "nyholm/psr7": "^1.3",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^9.0.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.17",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.67",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^2.0",
    "twilio/sdk": "^6.14"
},
```

Any ideas? I searched all forums but found no answer... :(

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this issue with file permissions not being set properly in the past.
Remember that your storage folder sits above your website public root. Check that IIS and PHP both have permission to write to this folder.

This may help:
[Add writing permission to PHP on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887131/add-writing-permission-to-php-on-iis-7)