# why I can't upload file data on my Vue laravel app if auth:api middleware is used. If middleware is escaped its upload the file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

My local Developement tools: Using Laragon for local server. using PhpStorm
**Database: Mysql.**
**Jwt Authentication: Passport.**
My front-end app vue is separate from the back-end laravel.
I am using axios to send the form data from my vue app to laravel app.
I have also set the Content-type Multipart/form-data.

Here is my log file

**I am using laragon for my local development**
2021-03-04 13:49:13] local.ERROR: The file  cannot be opened. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The file  cannot be opened. at I:\laragon\www\AuthenticationUsingPassport\vendor
yholm\psr7\src\Factory\Psr17Factory.php:46)
[stacktrace]

This question elaborate the problem:[Failed image upload Laravel and Windows Server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890957/failed-image-upload-laravel-and-windows-server-2019)
but its on windows server.

Comment: You should add some more detail about what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and what problems resulted. I would take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips on how to ask questions to make it easier for people to contribute answers.

Comment: @HenryTwist. I have edited the question. it would be very kind if any solution can be provided.

Comment: Well, I have solved it. I have to run the laragon with administrative permission on my windows.